# Caputure Signatures in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, activex, electronic-signature

I am going to start to work with electronic signatures for a website for my company. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on best practices and/or implementations. Note, I am not asking for anyone to spoon feed me code. I want to get ideas on how to go about it. I would like to be able to use a usb signature pad and submit the signature to the website with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to capture the image from the device you will need an ActiveX (or Java Applet) control since browsers security policy won't allow you to access the device. You might want to tag the question with ActiveX to get a better response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I've used with success before is to use JavaScript to capture mouse movement. Basically, the idea is to have a region of your page that tracks every "mouse move" event's pointer coordinates relative to the top left of the container element. Store these coordinates in a JavaScript array.

On the server side, you can use these coordinates as points to put black pixels, which will represent your signature.

I don't know if something like this already exists as an MVC control, but I know [this has been done in ASP.NET WebForms](http://www.websignaturecapture.com/).

I don't know how you'll be able to integrate a signature pad without ActiveX, unless the pad can display a section, or all, of the screen.